# How to find the intersection between 2 skimage.measure.LineModelND objects?

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, line, scikit-image

Here is a description of what I am trying to accomplish. I have a set of 3D points and I am trying to fit 2 lines on those points and after defining those lines I want to find their intersection.

Here are more details about what I have done so far, starting from the begin. I have a set of 3D points stored in an `np.ndarray` of shape `(N, 3)` one can find the points [here](https://paste-bin.xyz/28866).

After that I use the scikit-image library to define the lines using ransac. And I get lines of the type [LineModelND](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=intersection#skimage.measure.LineModelND) which are defined by a point (origin) and a unit vector (direction) using ransac. Here is a code snippet. And after one line is fitted to the data, I fit on the outliers another line, so now I have 2 LineModelND objects and I want find their intersection. Any ideas ?

```
model = LineModelND()
model.estimate(proj_points_array)

model_robust, inliers = ransac(proj_points_array, LineModelND, min_samples=2,
                               residual_threshold=0.02, max_trials=1000)

print('line params: ', model_robust.params, ' line is type of: ', type(model_robust))

outliers = inliers == False

model_2 = LineModelND()
model_2.estimate(proj_points_array[outliers,:])
```

[Here is the geometry of the points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JffTw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found so far is to use the [`skspatial.objects.Line.intersect_line`](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference/Line/methods/skspatial.objects.Line.intersect_line.html#skspatial.objects.Line.intersect_line) method. This method requires the points to be co-planar and the lines to actually have an intersection or in other words to not be parallel. The LineModelND returns a line model defined by point and direction as the line object definition of the [skspatial.objects.Line](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference/skspatial.objects.Line.html) object, so after defining the skspatial Lines you can use the intersect_line method of this class.

In my case, the lines are not coplanar. So I had to project the points to a plane, find the 2D intersection, compute the 3D axis value from the planar equation and then reverse the transformation. This results to the [following output](https://pasteboard.co/KdZKtggmoRm3.png) (I can't post images so I've posted a link to the image.